# MySQL insert on duplicate key update PK AI

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates, auto-increment

I have test table with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id_pc` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_vendor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_product` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `test` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_pc`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_vendor` (`id_vendor`,`id_product`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

As you can see UQ key is set on 2 columns different from PK which is AI.

Simple test query:

```
INSERT INTO test(id_vendor, id_product, test) 
VALUES (1,1,1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE test = 1;
```

Every time I run query it increments AUTO_INCREMENT value (so no insert is made, only update). Is this normal behavior or am I missing something?

Comment: `Every time I run query it increments AUTO_INCREMENT value (so no insert is made, only update). Is this normal behavior or am I missing something?` first of all what do you mean by this? are you achieving what you want or want something else?

Comment: What do you want to happen?  Are you wanting to have to auto-increment keys? or are you wanting it to only insert when the primary key is free?

Comment: 'Gaps' are what worries me. Real table has a bit more different structure - with 'x' additional fields that change often and PK is not int (Number of records is moderate). So by often update table auto-increment value will eventually get out of scope, and what will happen to new insert than? So what i ask is this normal behavior of mysql to increment that value on each 'duplicate key update' when update is executed?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the subject from another perspective: MySQL will not *reset* the table's AUTO_INCREMENT value unless you tell it to (e.g., via `ALTER TABLE` or `TRUNCATE TABLE` queries). In your case, it obviously need to use a value so it can compose the insert before it can decide it's a duplicate.

Also:

- If there's a duplicate key, changing the value of a column that isn't part of any key will not help.
- Values obtained via AUTO_INCREMENT are supposed to be meaningless. If you are worried about gaps, you are using the wrong tool for the job.